# UPDATE in postgresql with JOINS

Tags: postgresql

I have a form where some input has a value that is made with this query:

```
SELECT e.tree.nombre
FROM d.p
JOIN e.theme ON id = id_capa
LEFT JOIN e.tree ON e.theme.id_tree = e.tree.id
WHERE id_capa = 816
```

`e` and `d` are schemas. The `id_capa = 816` is passed as an argument to the query from the form that I'm editing. It returns a value correctly. Now I want to edit that value on my form, so I need to UPDATE but I have multiple tables, I read that I can't do an UPDATE with JOINS, how should I do that UPDATE?

Comment: Do you need to update data located on multiple tables, or do you just need data from a secondary table to know which rows to update in a single table?

Answer (score 1):

In your original SQL query, the table `d.p` is not used, neither in `SELECT` nor in conditions. So it can be skipped; the query can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT e.tree.nombre
FROM e.theme
  LEFT JOIN e.tree ON e.theme.id_tree = e.tree.id
WHERE e.theme.id = 816
```

Since the query selects values from table joined with `LEFT JOIN`, the result can be `NULL`, ie joined record from `e.tree` table can be missed. In this case there is nothing to update.

Existing matching record can be updated with the query:

```
UPDATE e.tree
SET nombre = <NEW_VALUE>
FROM e.theme
WHERE e.theme.id = 816 AND e.theme.id_tree = e.tree.id
```